# Can Hangfire schedule jobs do this?

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I am evaluating Hangfire for an upcoming ASP.net Core project that has several scheduled and reoccurring tasks that need to execute independently of users clicking on web pages.  I know that HangFire can do this if the web application is started because a request has come in.  I need to know whether or not HangFire can execute a scheduled task between being rebooted and the first web request coming in.

**Example:**  Web server is rebooted at 11pm, and no web requests will come in to cause the web server to spin up until 5am the next morning.  A scheduled task needs to be performed at 1AM.  Will Hangfire execute this task even though the web application hasn't been started by an incoming request?

If it can, is there a certain setup I need to do to allow this?

Details, if needed:
We are going to be using Kestrel hosted in a windows service and sitting behind an NGINX reverse proxy.  This setup could be modified if needed to make HangFire meet this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running under IIS it would be a real problem, see [Making ASP.NET application always running](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#)

But it should not be problem for ASP.NET CORE with kestrel, [see](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#comment-2884344054)

> It is not necessary for ASP.NET Core, because application is exposed
> by a console application that it already always on – there are no
> timeouts, no suspends and other optimization techniques yet. All you
> need to do is to use supervisor as written in the official docs for
> Linux, or use Windows Service with automatic start time, when running
> on Windows.